# Undefined Reference in C++ using static class

Tags: c++, static, inner-classes, class-variables, qualified-name

I've been looking for an answer to this for several hours.  Even though I have a workaround I'd like to understand the problem.  I get an undefined reference error when linking the following:

.h:

```
class Test
{
public:
    class Class1
    {
    public:
        Class1(int i);
        int x;      
        void Inc();
    };
    
    static Class1 one;  
    static int F1();    
    
    
};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"
Test::Class1 one(0);
void Test::Class1::Inc()
{
    x++;
}
Test::Class1::Class1(int i)
{
    x = i;
}

int Test::F1()
{
    //extern Test::Class1 one;  
    one.Inc();
    return one.x;
}
```

I get an undefined reference to Test:one in the F1 function.  If I add the extern Test::Class1 one it seems to work.  Why is this necessary?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `Test::Class1 one(0);`?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `Test::Class1 one(0);` should be `Test::Class1 Test::one(0);`

Comment: @kevin This is not a simple typo,  but a usual confusion when using nested types.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little confusing due to the nested class, but it's as simple as:

```
Test::Class1 Test::one(0);
```

---

The following statement in your code, just defines a global objet `one` that happens to be of a nested type:  `Test::Class1` :

```
Test::Class1 one(0);
```

If it wasn't of a nested type, you'd immediately have noticed the missing qualifier ;-)